# Good practice on spacing

Tags: spacing, best-practices

In various places, in passing, I've seen mention of various good practices regarding well-behaved spacing in LaTeX. For example, `Dr. Who` should really be written `Dr.\ Who` or `Dr.~Who` to get the right spacing (Since the full stop is not the end of a sentence.

Similarly with integrals: `\int x\, dx` should be preferred to `\int x dx` to properly space out the "`dx`".

But this is all piecemeal advice for specific circumstances: what are the general principles guiding when to pay attention to how LaTeX is dealing with your spaces?

Comment: Look at Will's post, [Correct punctuation spaces](http://latex-alive.tumblr.com/post/827168808/correct-punctuation-spaces).  He doesn't address formulae there, but maybe he'll be along here later.

Comment: @Charles Stewart So `\@` is a "semantic" way of telling TeX where to end a sentence or not, while `\ ` is a syntactic explicit spacing command, right? That's helpful...

Comment: yes, that's right. You should consider `\@.` a "sentence-ending period" and `.\@` an "abbreviation period" .

Comment: AFAIK, those corrections are needed when you're using `\nonfrenchspacing` — which is default. However, most modern typesetters don’t use additional space between sentences. This is, as Bringhurst points out in _The elements of typographic style_, rather Victorian. Personally, I always use `\frenchspacing` and don't have to care about this kind of correction, although I do use ties and everything.

Comment: `Doctor Who` should never be abbreviated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You want to keep in mind all the irregularities in your text: places where superficially uniform text turns out not to be uniform.  You give periods in abbreviations as examples; the reason they are is that a period does not usually go inside a sentence, but in this case, it does (and only a speaker of idiomatic English could know that, not TeX).  The differential in an integral is another example: it is the same text as the integrand, but it is not part of the integrand (in this case, I could imagine TeX being written to look out for this, but there are probably good reasons it doesn't).

You should, of course, also look out for constructions which are superficially different but in fact are not.  These may center on certain TeX idioms: for example, if you were programming in plain TeX (which you are not, and so you should not actually write this ever) you might do the following:

```
The following {\it italic text} is not well-spaced.
```

If you set that, you may see that the word *text* is a little too close to "is".  In the TeXbook, Knuth reminds you to put in an "italic correction".  However, now that LaTeX has `\textit{...}`, which takes care of this, you probably never even learned what an italic correction is.  So this is a non-example.  The point remains, however, that certain TeX constructions break the flow of the text (in particular, grouping) and you need to pay attention to the typeset result to see if they broke the spacing.

Vertical space can also be an issue, and harder to deal with.  Knuth also warns against using tall symbols in the text (like `\frac{1}{2}` instead of `1/2`) because they force the lines apart.  Thus, you need to scrutinize all the inline math you write for tall symbols, and consider using displayed equations.  Sometimes you can work around this using `\smash` if you know there is space and TeX doesn't.

Inline math causes another problem with TeX's line breaking algorithm, because it won't break at a lot of places in an equation, commas being the notorious example.  Thus, write `$a$, $b$, and $c$` rather than `$a, b, \text{ and } c$` or even `$a, b$, and $c$`.  Knuth also wants you to put a tie in: `and~$c$`; I confess that I never use ties.  Like manual spacing corrections in equations, they seem like they should be reserved for final polishing (I mean, if `Dr. House` is in the middle of a line, it's not going to break).

In short, you need to watch for scope changes, mode changes, and changes in "semantic scope", where the last one is totally impossible to communicate to TeX and the other two are still insidious.  However, you should not be afraid to "just try it" and see whether you really do have a problem.  It is much faster to let TeX do whatever it does (and with TeX, "whatever it does" is sometimes all you can say easily) than to try to anticipate it.

Comment: I think the correct approach would be to write `Dr.~House` the very first time, without worrying or checking whether or not it will occur at the end of a line. No matter what happens afterwards in the preceding text, it will still not break across a line.

Comment: @Niel: That would be better, yes.  Likewise writing `a, b, and~c` or any of the other picky things Knuth suggests using ties for.  But it's an extra processing step in my brain that turns out to be a waste of time as I revise in-place umpteen times.  I feel that this belongs to the editing phase rather than the composition phase, and usually, there are more important things to do there when I get to it.  So I never get around to inserting ties.

Comment: I think it's most helpful because it's very easy to go through, add the ties in the editing phase, and then make a minor wording change that causes new bad breaks and so you have to go back and redo the ties. Better to just train yourself to do it right the first time. The most common place I see this messed up is before a citation. If one always write `~\cite{...}` then this is never a problem.

Comment: Apart from line breaking, there's another reason to write `Dr.~House`, that is… spacing. TeX automatically lengthens spaces after a period, that is, spacing between sentences is slightly longer than between words. This should be avoided (using `~` or `\ `) when a period does not end a sentence.

Comment: @fudo: ah, I like that reason.  And the tie is one character shorter than the escaped space, too.

Comment: I agree that it's best to add ties as late as possible. Every time you add a tie, you run the risk of typing, say, `Smith~ \cite{smith}` by accident and getting too much space. Also, sometimes it's hard to say whether a paragraph looks better with or without a "psychologically bad" line break; what if by preventing such a break you add three consecutive hyphenated lines to your paragraph? It's probably best to decide these issues when you're almost certain your wording is in its final form.

Comment: "The differential in an integral is another example: it is the same text as the integrand, but it is not part of the integrand (in this case, I could imagine TeX being written to look out for this, but there are probably good reasons it doesn't)"  My Russian colleague places the differential at the beginning of the integral.  Looks weird to me, but he would be unhappy if LaTeX dictated otherwise through preconditioned notions.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It's a physics convention, I believe.  Makes sense if you think of the integral as an operator.  Note, I wasn't questioning the design in this case, though like I said, this convention *could* be accommodated, for example by defining a `\dx` macro that chose the correct spacing based on its location.

Comment: @fudo What if you want a non-breakable space after a period ending a sentence? ".~" will shorten the otherwise longer space! :(

Comment: @Andrestand I can't imagine a situation where that would be useful, and I'm afraid that TeX/LaTeX developers could not either…

Answer (score 33):

Here is a short summary of my spacing policy.

- For inline text: simply use non-breaking spaces anywhere that you would never want the line to break. Think about doing so any time you are doing something unusual in your text, such as  `Dr.~Who` ,  `Figure~\ref{fig:a}` , and ad-hoc inline lists such as  `(a)~this, or (b)~that` .
- Almost all macros eat spaces after them. So if in doubt, force spaces after any macro, `\like\ this`. If you define macros such as

  ```
  \newcommand\etc{\emph{etc.}}
  ```

  then being mindful of this rule will, as a side effect, properly deal with the spaces following such italicized abbreviations.

The additional ideas below may not be "best practices", but they *are* practices that I have converged upon due to the demands of having to read and write my own work over and over again, and wanting things to be as easy to read as possible.

- Sometimes, in mathematical contexts, you know in advance that you will need more space because a certain piece of math is always written in that way. In such cases, you should think of defining a macro to take care of it. For instance, for use in integrals, it would be good policy to define a macro for the differential symbol `d`, as follows:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand\d[1]{\mspace{6mu}\mathrm{d}#1\@ifnextchar\d{\mspace{-3mu}}{}}
  \makeatother
  ```

  (This assumes you don't need to use the Icelandic character 'eth', which is the original meaning of  `\d` .) This macro adds spacing on the left of a differential form, but less if what preceded it was another differential. You can then write

  ```
  $ \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) \d\theta \d\phi $
  ```

  and get an output which is more approximately what you would want by default.
- I always look at the typeset version of my mathematics to ensure that it is easy to scan visually, and add space where I think it is necessary to help break the mathematics into easily parsed blocks of "tokens". So I make liberal use of the `\,` , `\;` , `\!` , and `\quad` macros.

Comment: I like your `\d`.

Comment: There is also the `xspace` package which helps with spacing after macros. Also, which spacing commands are bigger and which smaller?

Comment: @Seamus: the order is `\!`, `\,`, `\:`, `\;`, `\quad`, and `\qquad`. In units of `mu` (= 1/18 `em`, determined from the surrounding font size), their widths are -3, 3, 4, 5, 18, and 36.

Comment: @Niel where does `\ ` fit?

Comment: @Seamus: I don't know. It produces a "normal" inter-word space, with the corresponding relationship to the em-size of the font. I suspect that this will vary from font to font, but I can't say definitively.

Comment: @Niel: The best definition for the differential in integrals and in differential forms in general is `\mathop{}\!d` (use `\mathrm{d}` if you prefer). This adds the correct spacing in all cases that I know.

Comment: Better to use cleveref than `Figure~\ref{...}` – what if you change your mind and want `fig.` later?

Comment: And `\like{} this` seems to be more common.

Comment: @Mk12: is there any advantage to writing it `\like{} this`, however? Writing it `\this\ way` is one character shorter and involves fewer keystrokes. As to `cleveref.sty`, that's a pretty good argument, though in the past I've had interoperation problems with `hyperref.sty`, which means arguably you should use the `\autoref` feature of the latter package anyway.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: Both work, but I prefer the empty brackets because you can just use it consistently, rather than only adding the \ when a space follows. With cleveref, make sure that you load hyperref and cleveref last, and they should play nicely.

Comment: Regarding `\d`, I would recommend using `\dif` from the [commath](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/commath) package.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Where does `~` fit in that list?

Answer (score 13):

A tricky issue and an idea:

1. Will noted that in the when TeX typesets "(etc.)", TeX puts extra space after the close parenthesis, so treating it as the end of a sentence, not the end of an abbreviation.  See his [Correct punctuation spaces](http://latex-alive.tumblr.com/post/827168808/correct-punctuation-spaces);
2. An SO thread about how to implement the macros Will suggested at the end of his item, [Correct way to define macros \etc \ie in latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282319/correct-way-to-define-macros-etc-ie-in-latex/3285603#3285603), showed up lots of tricky issues implementation them.  The accepted answer, by Jukka, said, pace Will, that the right thing is just to learn all the workarounds for TeX's foibles.

My stab at implementing a `\latinabbrev` macro-defining macro convinced me, after much time, that it's hard to get the definition right, but it is possible, and the corner cases are so tricky that you can't expect most LaTeX users to understand them well enough to always do the right thing in their writing.

Answer (score 13):

Just about the integrals: Personally, I wouldn't consider `\int x\ dx` good practice; the space is too large. I always use `\int x\,dx`.

Comment: Actually, that's right. I was reading an article about this on my phone, and the commas were too small for me to see comfortably the first time...

Comment: I edited the question to reflect this point.

Comment: .. I stumbled on this old question, shouldn't mathematical operators such as `d` be in upright roman?

Comment: @saltypen: I actually don't like them upright. The mathematics community is divided on this question. I use upright only for stuff like `$x_{\max}$`, where it is clear that the "max" is _text_. This is not the case with "d".

Answer (score 2):

Actually, when `\nonfrenchspacing` is in use, it's most correct (as I understand it) to put an `\@` between every uppercase letter and sentence punctuation mark, not just sentence-ending punctuation marks. For instance, ideally you should type `They use three languages at NASA\@: C\@; MATLAB\@, the best; and Pascal.`. Under `\nonfrenchspacing`, colons, semicolons, and commas all have space factor codes greater than 1000, so without the `\@`'s in my example you wouldn't get perfect spacing after "NASA:", "C;", or "MATLAB,". (You don't get extra space after semicolons or commas, but spaces after those punctuation marks stretch more and shrink less than a normal interword space.)

Still, all those `\@`'s can make a TeX file quite hard to read. So I tend not to bother with `\@`'s between uppercase letters and commas or semicolons. Lamport's LaTeX 2e manual doesn't say to add them there, and the *TeXbook* only implies that something goes "wrong" in those situations (see page 76), so I assume that this is a reasonable compromise.