# Abbreviations and spacing

Tags: macros, spacing, xspace

I'm sure this is a pretty standard questions that's been asked (and answered!) a hundered times before, so apologies for boring people.

In LaTeX, I'd like to write a macro for abbreviations, such as, "e.g." or "i.e." but I'd like LaTeX to get the spacing after the trailing dot right: sometimes I enclose the "e.g." in commas and sometimes I don't, depending on the document I'm writing:

```
A lot of fruits contain vitamin C, e.g., lemons and oranges.

To practice a sport like e.g. rugby, a good level of fitness is adviced.
```

(Please let's not discuss whether this use of commas is correct or not.)

How can I write a macro `\eg` that gets the spacing right automatically for both cases?

Comment: This question pretty seems to be the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/is-a-period-after-an-abbreviation-the-same-as-an-end-of-sentence-period . If you don't want the bigger space after the period, enter a `\ ` after `e.g.`, like `e.g.\ rugby`

Comment: @Matten: I disagree.  The point of _this_ question is how to have a macro put in the space.  The point of that question is how much space to put in (and how to control it).

Comment: ok, you're right

Comment: I know this is orthogonal to your question, but IMO if you care enough about your document that you want to control the spacing after periods, then you should care enough about the text to avoid abbreviations like "e.g."

Comment: @Thomas: You might also be interested in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/good-practice-on-spacing/5515#5515) to a related question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the package [xspace](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/xspace.html) for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand*{\eg}{e.g.\xspace}

\begin{document}
A lot of fruits contain vitamin C, \eg, lemons and oranges.

To practice a sport like \eg rugby, a good level of fitness is adviced.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, the spacing here is incorrect.  Thanks to Will's comment on an answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/is-a-period-after-an-abbreviation-the-same-as-an-end-of-sentence-period, the correct definition is `\newcommand*{\eg}{e.g.\@\xspace}`

Comment: @Andrew: This still doesn't handle punctuation that needs double spacing at the end of a sentence, e.g., in "There were all sorts of farmyard animals there: rabbits, pigs, \etc".  [Some code of mine from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282319/correct-way-to-define-macros-etc-ie-in-latex/3285603#3285603) does handle this, although it doesn't treat "!" and "?", and its use of `expl3` makes it a bit heavyweight.

Comment: @Charles: ouch!  Mind you, the example given was e.g. and I can't think of _that_ going at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @Andrew: "Don't use the three most common Latin abbreviations, i.e., etc., i.e., and e.g."

Comment: @Bruno: Very witty.

Comment: -1 As it is this answer is simply wrong and doesn't work. The asker should remove the "close".