# Macros for common abbreviations

Tags: macros, spacing, acronyms, xspace

Common abbreviations are surprisingly tricky to format correctly.  I'd like some simple macros for them, to be used like so:

```
You should eat more fruit, \eg apples, bananas, oranges, \etc.
```

There are (at least) three (interrelated) problems to overcome in defining this:

1. If used at the end of a sentence, we end up with doubled-up periods.  Simply leaving off the period in the macro seems ugly (especially for things like 'e.g.', 'i.e.', ...).  A better solution calls for something like `\consumeif{.}`, but I can't find a beast.
2. The macro should include the behavior of `\xspace`.
3. It should also produce correct spacing depending on whether it ends a sentence, like the logic of `\@`.

How would I (you) write such a macro?  *Note: I'm aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/abbreviations-and-spacing) and others like it, but the answers don't resolve my problems.*

Comment: `\etc` doesn't even save you any keystrokes!? I think I just wouldn't bother. Do you really need a macro to save you from writing `e.g.` or more properly `e.g.\ `

Comment: @Seamus I like to use `\eg` to expand to, literally, ‘for example’, but sometimes to use the short-hand abbreviation in a paper or some such.

Comment: @Will I think that sort of thing could more fruitfully be handled by your editor of choice. I know a guy who has emacs automatically change ` st ` into ` spacetime ` ...

Comment: @Seamus True, but I like to italicize most abbreviations.  (Yes, many style guides disagree with this.)  A macro is definitely better than writing out `\textit{i.e.\@\xspace}`.

Comment: I guess, in terms of code readability, a macro beats having your editor automatically typeout all that, yes. That's a good point. But I agree that you shouldn't be italicising abbreviations...

Comment: On another note, I like to add an `\,` in acronyms like "e.g." or "i.e.". This makes it clear that there are actually two words behind it, but the space doesn't look too big, as a regular space or `~` would. (The German typographical quick reference [typokurz](http://www.zvisionwelt.de/typokurz.pdf) recommends this as well.)

Comment: \newcommand{\mydefinedfullstopabbreviation}{.}

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think the `\eg` and `\ie` macros should be defined differently to `\etc`, because they will never be at the end of a sentence. You can simply use `\@\xspace` at the end to ensure a space with the correct width if one is required. For `\etc` you can use `\@ifnextchar{.}{<yes>}{<no>}` to check for a following full stop.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand*{\eg}{e.g.\@\xspace}
\newcommand*{\ie}{i.e.\@\xspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\etc}{%
    \@ifnextchar{.}%
        {etc}%
        {etc.\@\xspace}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
You should eat more fruit, \eg apples, bananas, oranges, \etc. Next sentence.

\noindent
You should eat more fruit, \eg, apples, bananas, oranges, \etc but also tomatoes.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, _e.g._ & _i.e._ can occur at the end of a sentence―this very sentence, _e.g._

Comment: @J.C.Salomon: I'm not an English native speaker myself. However, I never have seen it used at the end of an sentence so far.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, it is an obscure usage, which is why I used it in my comment above for illustration.

Answer (score 17):

Phil Ratcliffe has recently posted to CTAN two packages to deal with this question:

- [`xpunctuate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpunctuate) “provides the commands `\xperiod`, `\xcomma` and `\xperiodcomma`, which follow a similar procedure to that of `\xspace`, and insert punctuation *if and only if* it is necessary,” and
- [`foreign`](http://ctan.org/pkg/foreign) which, among other things, uses the commands from `xpunctuate` to define `\eg` and `\ie` as the OP requests.

These commands attempt to correctly handle sentence spacing via a simple convention, better illustrated than described:

- “`The forest is filled with lions, tigers, bears, \etc.`” becomes
  “`The forest is filled with lions, tigers, bears, {\em etc}.`”
- “`The forest is filled with lions, tigers, bears, \etc!`” becomes
  “`The forest is filled with lions, tigers, bears, {\em etc}.!`”
- “`Lions, tigers, bears, \etc fill the forest.`” becomes
  “`Lions, tigers, bears, {\em etc}.\@ fill the forest.`”

(Actually, the font selection is a bit more complicated than I’ve shown.)

There’s even code that inserts a comma after mid-sentence `\ie` & `\eg`. (This comma can be disabled via the `[UKenglish]` option.)

Comment: This looks like the better option to me. Would you mind to add an example of how to use `xpunctuate`?

Answer (score 1):

After reading @J. C. Salomons answer I think `xpunctuate` is suited best for this task. Since I do not need the extra functionality from the `foreign` package, I decided against using that one.

The implementation of the macro provided by the package was not trivial for me, so I expect others might struggle with this as well. Here is my definition of an `\eg` macro, using the `xpunctuate` package (make sure to load it in the preamble):

```
\providecommand{\eg}[0]{e.g\xperiod}
```

Explanation:

- `\providecommand` defines a new macro if the macro name is not already used. Otherwise it will issue an error. I choose this to not unknowingly overwrite an important macro of a different package which might break its functuality.
- This is followed by the macro name: `{\eg}`
- Then the number of arguments is defined, in this case `[0]`. This is optional, however I like to make it explicit.
- Last, the macro is defined. It consists of `e.g`, followed by `xpunctuate`'s macro `\xperiod`. This will insert a period and an interword space if the macro is followed by another word, a period and no space if it is followed by punctuation and nothing if it is followed by a period, i.e. at the end of a sentence.

This should handle all different usecases for abbreviations correctly.