# How to prevent getting a space after an abbreviation using the abbrevs package?

Tags: spacing, acronyms, xspace

If I use the `abbrevs` package and define a \newabbrev using the following code

```
\newabbrev\gb{Great Britain}
```

and use it in the following example (taken from the [xspace package documentation](http://www-control.eng.cam.ac.uk/~pcr20/latex/xspace.pdf)):

```
\gb, a small island off the coast of France
```

I get "Great Britain , a small island off the coast of France", which has a superfluous space inserted before the comma

In the xspace package documentation, they also defines an abbreviation for "Great Britain", but using `\newcommand` instead of `\newabbrev`, and they are also having the problem with the superfluous space before the comma. They solve it by putting the macro `\xspace` after the full name, i.e. `Great Britain\xspace`. When I follow their example and redefine the abbreviation as

```
\newabbrev\gb{Great Britain\xspace}
```

it has the opposite effect, i.e., an *extra* superfluous space is added before the comma (which I can't illustrate here). I have also tried to insert `\@` before `xspace` (which I found out you could do in [this quite similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/abbreviations-and-spacing#comment11016_6858)), but that has no effect.

Any idéa of how to prevent an abbreviation defined with `\newabbrev` to insert a space after the abbreviation has been used? The reason I'm using the `abbrevs` package is because it provides a way of using one expansion of the abbreviation the first time it is used, and another expansion the resting times. I could just as well change to some other package that allowed me to do the same thing.

Comment: Said simply, none of the example in the documentation of `abbrevs` works as advertised. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the `abbrevs` package. It's supposed to test the following token of the abbreviation against the tokens in `\nospacelist` and insert `\space` if it is not part of `\nospacelist`. However, the macro responsible for the test checks the wrong conditional:

```
\newcommand\maybe@space@{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \expandafter   \@tfor
    \expandafter \reserved@a
    \expandafter :%
    \expandafter =%
                 \nospacelist
                 \do \t@st@ic
  \if@tempswa
    \space
  \fi
}
```

It tests `\@tempswa` is true but since the macro `\t@st@ic` (which is defined in `latex.ltx` and does the actual testing here) uses `\maybe@ic`

```
\def \t@st@ic {%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\reserved@b\expandafter=\reserved@a\relax
  \ifx\reserved@b\@let@token
    \maybe@icfalse
    \@break@tfor
  \fi
}
```

it should use/check for that one. A minor redefinition of `\maybe@space@` solves the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abbrevs}
\newabbrev\gb{Great Britain}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maybe@space@{%
  % \@tempswatrue % <= this is in the original
  \maybe@ictrue % <= this is new
  \expandafter   \@tfor
    \expandafter \reserved@a
    \expandafter :%
    \expandafter =%
                 \nospacelist
                 \do \t@st@ic
  % \if@tempswa % <= this is in the original
  \ifmaybe@ic % <= this is new
    \space
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\gb, a small island \\
\gb is an island

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't it easier to use `xspace`? Maybe something like `\let\maybe@space@\xspace`

Comment: @Marco Sure, that works just as fine, at least for the abbreviations (I haven't done much testing and never used `abbrevs` before...). It's still a bug in the package, though.

Comment: Of course. I wanted to provide an alternative approach ;-).

Comment: @cgnieder: Thanks, that seems to do the trick.