# How to format CE/BCE?

Tags: fontsize

Yes, there is the `abbrevs` package. It provides me with AM, PM, BC and AD. But what would be a sensible way to format the "Common Era" / "Before Common Era" prefixes / suffixes?

Comment: I'm not a nativ english speaker. I can't see your problem. Can you please explain it a little bit more, for example with showing a MWE and/or a screenshot which shows what you have and what you want? What has the tag fontsize to do with your question?

Comment: Why not define analogous commands to `\AM`, `\PM` ...? `\AM` is defined by the `abbrevs` package as follows: `\newcommand{\AM}{\DateMark{a.m}}`

Comment: @cgnieder: Thanks, that helps. In general, how do you look up these definitions? Where can you find them?

Comment: @chaosflaws They're mentioned in the implementation part of the `abbrevs` documentation. If they weren't I'd either have opened the `abbrevs.sty` file or would have used `\meaning\AM`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define them analogous to the definitions of `\BC` and `\AD` which are defined by the `abbrevs` package as

```
\newcommand\AD{\DateMark{a.d}}
\newcommand\BC{\DateMark{b.c}}
```

The `\DateMark` macro takes care of eventual following punctuation and formats its contents with `\DateMarkSize` and `\scshape`. `\DateMarkSize` is `\small` per default which I'd change: the punctation marks in e.g. *A.D.* else will be of different size and it seems strange to me to use a fixed size for the marks, anyway: think of using them in a footnote or something...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abbrevs}
\newcommand*\CE{\DateMark{c.e}}
\newcommand*\BCE{\DateMark{b.c.e}}
\begin{document}

\BCE \CE

\CE, \CE.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm .... I don't get this output from this code. Do you know if anything changed?

Comment: It seems this code worked three years ago. No idea if there have been changes. I never really used `abbrevs`

Comment: Me neither. Somebody asked a question. I think it is a bug, though.

Comment: Which reminds me of  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59884/ `abbrevs` *has* bugs

Comment: For reference: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329657/trouble-formatting-datemark-w-abbrevs-package-bce#.

Comment: Seems the new question is a duplicate. And according to the comments I even made a bug report.

Comment: Too bad nothing seems to have changed .... (It would be different if the author couldn't find a fix, but one is provided ....)