# Spacing Issues with Use of Abbrevs Package

Tags: gap, chronology, horizontal-spacing

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{abbrevs}

\begin{document}
By 2100 \BC, almost universal corruption prevailed.
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I adjust (reduce) the horizontal space between 2100 and B.C.; as well as reduce the gap between B.C. and the comma?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59840/208544, I think

Comment: The link you provide would seem to apply only to the space *after* the abbreviation.

Comment: The usage of `\BC` in the documentation (bottom of page 4) does not use a preceding space, e.g. `2100\BC`.