# What is the difference between \cite and ~\cite?

Tags: line-breaking, citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why I should put a ~ before \ref command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/why-i-should-put-a-before-ref-command)

I see the two used fairly interchangeably but have never read what the difference is between them...

Comment: `~` is a _tie_ ie non-breaking space. Say `word~\cite{...}` ensure that we cannot have a line break between `word` and `\cite{}`. It is also very hand for regular references, I usually use `~` in front of all my references.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why I should put a `~` before `\ref` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9633/5764)