# Label specific state in the algorithmic environment

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms

if I have this code

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \label{alg:the_alg}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE operation 0
    \STATE operation 1
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I can make a reference to `alg:the_alg`. But, how I can make a reference to a `STATE` in `algorithmic` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You would use the same technique as you would with a regular label. The reference will be to the line number inside `algorithmic`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{This is an algorithm}
  \label{alg:the_alg}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE operation 0 \label{op0}
    \STATE operation 1 \label{op1}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

See Algorithm~\ref{alg:the_alg}. More specifically, Operation~\ref{op1}.
\end{document}
```

Consider using the compatible (modernized) [`algorithmicx` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) which offers `algpseudocode`. Here's a duplicate of the above MWE, now with the updated `algpseudocode` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{This is an algorithm}
  \label{alg:the_alg}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State operation 0 \label{op0}
    \State operation 1 \label{op1}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

See Algorithm~\ref{alg:the_alg}. More specifically, Operation~\ref{op1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: in references, why some people use `~`, example: `~\ref` and not a whitespace `\ref` ?

Comment: @JuanPablo: To avoid a line break between the two since they're considered a "single unit". See [Why should I put a `~` before `\ref` or `\cite`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9633/5764)

Comment: Thank you for your solution!