# new command for the dx of intergral.

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the proper way to typeset a differential operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator)

```
\newcommand{d}[1]{\:\textrm{d}{#1}}
```

That is my new comamnd for writing the *dx* of an intergral.  Just wanted to be able to type this in my code.

```
\d{x}  <<<where the x is the variable of integration>>>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Related Question: [Should I `\mathrm` the d in my integrals?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60545/should-i-mathrm-the-d-in-my-integrals)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\newcommand\d[1]{\:\textrm{d}#1} 
\renewcommand\d[1]{\:\textrm{d}#1} % if \d is already defined
```

only for a definition of an environment you use `\newenvironment{env}`.
Another useful definition is:

```
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

in your definition you do not really need the argument and using `\mathrm` makes more sense, then it takes the d from the same math font and not from the text font

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\d[1]{\:\textrm{d}#1}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
$\d x \textrm{ or } \diff x  $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok. uh.  so what do I type in the body?

Comment: `\d{x}` or `\d x` or `\diff x`

Comment: @MaoYiyi: You should not use `\d` as that is already used elsewhere.

Comment: @Herbert that didn't work.

Comment: @MaoYiyi: "that didn't work" is not a helpful message ... As Peter already mentioned, if the `\d` is already defined (for an accent), then use `\renewcommand\d`

Comment: @herbert, Sorry that I couldn't say more, I wish I could explain the messages that winEdt gives for wrong code.  I used.

Comment: @Herbert \newcommand\dx[1]{\:\textrm{d}#1}  and that worked.  I am very happy for you helpping me. You are very smart.

Comment: @MaoYiyi: see my edited answer

Comment: When I type I like to have the {} around stuff, personal taste.  So I was wondering would \newcommand*\diff[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}#1} work propertly?

Comment: @MaoYiyi: sure makes no difference

Comment: This `\diff` may cause a problem when being used with the `tipa` package, since the package redefined `\!`. A possible solution with `amsmath` is replacing `\!` in your definition by `\negthinspace`.

Comment: or simply use `\mkern-\thinmuskip`