# Quickly inserting spaces before differentials

Tags: spacing

Let's say I wrote a long document containing several math formulae and then I realized that I forgot to put the `\,` spaces before the differentials in, say, all the integrals. Is there a simple way to insert those fast?
Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    $\iint\limits_{S} |J|d\alpha d\beta$
    \lipsum[2]
    $\iint\limits_{S} |J|d\beta d\omega$
    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the future, do `\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}` and use `\diff\alpha`. For the present, search and replace.

Comment: The correct, upright version can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83061/194703): `\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` or anything that produces an *upright* `d`. (Imagine you want to integrate over some distance `d`, an italic differential `d` is just confusing and not (up)right.)

Answer (score 1):

For the quickest way, you can use search and replace (generally ctrl+H) for "d\" and replace it with "\,d\" or whatever spacing you desire. You can include the "|J|" for more precision.

Comment: What if I have several integrals over different variables, e.g. `d\alpha` and `dx`?