# Defining a macro with optional parameter

Tags: math-mode, macros

I like to define a macro with an optional parameter. As an example, consider a macro for the differential:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand\drm{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand\Drm[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d^#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^\infty \drm t \, f(t)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^\infty \Drm{3} r \, g(\bm{r})
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The macros for the differentials are taken from [an earlier post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60545/should-i-mathrm-the-d-in-my-integrals). Apart from my own question, why is there a `\mathop{}` in the definition of the differentials? But second, how can I achieve a macro that puts both of them together? Like it is with `\sqrt`, where you can do `\sqrt{x}` or `\sqrt[3]{x}`. I like to do `\drm` or `\drm[3]`.

Comment: It's best not to ask two questions at once. Nevertheless, are you aware of the package [physics](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics)?

Comment: No I am not. Looking into it.

Comment: What's the advantage from writing `\Drm{3}` instead of `\drm^{3}`? I see none.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you sure you want

```
\newcommand\Drm[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d^#1}}
```

rather than

```
\newcommand\Drm[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}^{#1}}
```

which would be rather more usual I think (It makes no difference if the superscript is a digit but try `n`) and you certainly need the `{}` around `#1` if there might be two digits.

To make the argument optional you could use

```
 \newcommand\Drm[1][]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}^{#1}}
```

But that makes `^{}` in the empty case which can affect spacing so better is

```
 \newcommand\Drm[1][\relax]{%
   \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\ifx\relax#1\relax\else^{#1}\fi}
```

where you omit the superscript in the default case.