# What does symbol ~ do in Latex?

Tags: symbols, accents, tilde

I noticed this symbol in an example. Including or excluding this from the source doesn't change anything. However, if I include `\~`, it puts a ~ on the first letter of the next word. So, what could be purpose of including `~` in the code? Also, how do I print the ~ only in my document?

Comment: Also please see [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363)

Comment: @clemens In Latex, aren't all spaces non-breaking spaces?

Comment: No. LaTeX will happily break a line between `one two` but it won't between `one~two`. The latter will stay in the same line together.

Comment: How should LaTeX spaces should be non-breaking by default if the most praised feature of (La)TeX ist the line-breaking and hyphenation algorithm?

Comment: See also [Why should I put a ~ before \ref or \cite?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/why-should-i-put-a-before-ref-or-cite) and [Good practise on spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5511/3083) for typical use cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `~` inserts a non-breaking space. This means that you tell the typesetting algorithm that it should not insert a linebreak here. This is useful when making references. For example, if you write

```
according to the Pythagorean theorem there is a lot to be learned 
form a triangle. You might see in equation \eqref{eq:1} there is
some need for
```

is typeset as

[image]

however,

```
according to the Pythagorean theorem there is a lot to be learned
form a triangle. You might see in equation~\eqref{eq:1} there is
some need for
```

will ensure that `equation` and `(1)` stay on the same line.

[image]