# Inserting a single space in integral

Tags: letterspacing

I'm trying to type up my homework, and I can't seem to figure out how to insert a blank horizontal space in this integral like my professor did...

His:

[image]

Mine:

[image]

I'm using

```
 $$\iint_S \left(\nabla \times \vec{F}\right) \cdot \vec{n} d\sigma,$$
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `\,` is the space to use. Don't use `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: @jbrow35: See [Why is `\( ... \)` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: You can see also the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/good-practice-on-spacing. There is a complete question for the space.

Answer (score 5):

You have a good eye for the details! So let's look at them more carefully.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{Attempt 1}\qquad&
%
  \iint_S \left(\nabla \times \vec{F}\right) \cdot \vec{n} d\sigma
%
\\
\text{Attempt 2}\qquad&
%
  \iint_S \left(\nabla \times \vec{F}\right) \cdot \vec{n}\,d\sigma
%
\\
\text{Attempt 3}\qquad&
%
  \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot \vec{n}\,d\sigma
%
\\
\text{Attempt 4}\qquad&
%
  \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot \vec{n}\diff\sigma
%
\\
\text{Check}\qquad& \frac{d\vec{F}}{dt}\\
\text{Check}\qquad& \frac{\diff\vec{F}}{\diff t}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Attempt 1 is your original code; attempt 2 has the suggested `\,`.

Can you spot the difference with attempt 3? Look at the centered dot: in attempt 2 it is not midway from the operands. Why is that? Note I removed `\left` and `\right`, which should not *generally* be used.

Attempt 4 uses `\diff\sigma` instead of `\,d\sigma`. This is better not only because you won't forget `\,`, but also because it allows to change all of your italic “d” for the differential into an upright one, should the need arise, by just modifying the definition.

---

*Added notes*

The last two lines are just for ensuring `\diff` doesn't add unwanted spaces in other situations: the two fractions are exactly the same.

Using `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` falls under the same category and is correct. However, one has always to be careful when doing `\renewcommand`.

Don't use `$$` in LaTeX under any circumstances, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code, borrowed from an answer on this site (I don't remember which one):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\!{}}

\begin{document}

\[ \iint_S (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \mathbf{n} \dd\sigma \]%

\end{document}
```

*Note:*  Don't use `$$ … $$` for displayed equations. It's plain TeX syntax, and it can give bad spacings. Use `\[ … \]` instead.
[image]

Comment: `\mathop{}\!d` seems easier; with `\mathrm` or not, according to one's preferences. As you see, the OP has an italic d.

Comment: @Bernard Very compliments for your reputations of 100k. Hi.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks a lot! This is a very warm site (which is not the case of all Stack Exchange sites!)

Comment: @Bernard I think this TEX.SE site is a big family and we have to help one another without envy. And +1 for your answer.