# When loading LaTeX files in vim (7.3) I get the error "perhaps you should insert a `~' before '\ref' "

Tags: vim

I have the over 30 errors in my LaTeX file, all over the `\ref{...}` command, and all following this similar pattern (I put it as a quote instead of code as it is long and code does not wrap)

> I returned and saw under the sun, that the race is not to the swift,
>   nor the battle to the strong, neither yet bread to the wise, nor yet
>   riches to men of understanding, nor yet favour to men of skill; but
>   time and chance happeneth to them all. \ref{bible:ecclesiastes}

Every time I get the following complaint over `\ref{...}`

```
perhaps you should insert a `~' before "\ref"
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Is this actually an *error*? Or is it just a suggestion that is output by `vim`? Is that the *exact* reference given?

Comment: @Werner it's actually an error. The exact error is `|6 error| perhaps you should insert a `~' before "\ref"` where 6 is the line number

Comment: @derobert feel free to recommend moving this page. The reason I put it here, as opposed to TeX.SE is because I felt it was more a problem with vim's syntax check than LaTex's syntax.

Comment: @puk: That's not default vim behavior. Maybe you've enabled a plugin (such as checksyntax) which is calling `chktex`? (and yes, I voted to move it; "latex editors" is explicitly given in the FAQ, so vim used for editing TeX would be OK there, I think )

Comment: @derobert I have `syntastic` on, but that is just for javascript. Also, I am using beautifiers for javascript and PHP. Besides that, I have not turned on any syntax checkers.

Comment: Duplicate in terms of reference: [Tilde and Slash in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11837/tilde-and-slash-in-latex), but not in terms of a `vim` solution.

Comment: @puk: `syntastic` also does error checking for a variety of filetypes, including LaTeX. For LaTeX, it uses the [`lacheck`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/lacheck) script, which gives the error message.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you write "`... this was written by \ref{foo}`" the following output is possible:

```
... this was written by
[1]
```

which looks ugly in fact of the linebreak. This is the reason why vim is very nice to you and told you that you should write: "`... this was written by~\ref{foo}`". Then your output is at least:

```
...  this  was  written 
by [1]
```

So it is not a LaTeX error, but an "error message" from vim.

Comment: LOL _almost_ makes the migration from SO pointless