# What does 'missing \@ before...' error mean in vim?

Tags: spacing, errors, punctuation, vim

I get this strange behavior when I have capitals before a period, like so

```
    1 \documentclass{article}
    2 \begin{document}
>>  3 Another possible protein blah blah blah from GRIP/ABP. Blah Blah Blah
    4 \end{document}
```

The error I generally get in vim is:

```
blahblah.tex|3 error| missing `\@' before `.' in "ABP."
```

What does that mean? Why do I get it? How do I fix it?

Comment: Pease add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem (including the preamble).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30054/5764 - the use of `\@` is meant to inform TeX about abbreviation-related periods and how to handle them. Not sure how to remove this behaviour from `vim`, but in your case, it seems you would need `... WWII\@.`

Comment: The error seems to be produced by `vim` running a syntax checker such as `syntastic`; see the comments to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37631/when-loading-latex-files-in-vim-7-3-i-get-the-error-perhaps-you-should-insert)

Comment: @egreg LOL I asked that question also.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following hopefully answers your "abbreviated questions":

1. `vim` suggests inserting `\@` before `.` in `...GRIP/ABP.` So, do it! The reason here is that `GRIP/ABP` or any capitalized word before a period is usually an abbreviation. And, in some instances, abbreviations have periods, while some don't. To treat the end-of-abbreviation period as an end-of-sentence period, like it is in your case, use

   ```
   Another possible protein blah blah blah from GRIP/ABP\@. Blah Blah Blah
   ```

   Here is a visual of the effect if you don't use it:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
   Another possible protein blah blah blah from GRIP/ABP. Blah Blah Blah \par
   Another possible protein blah blah blah from GRIP/ABP\@. Blah Blah Blah
   \end{document}​
   ```

   Note the difference in spacing *after* the period. The latter constitutes a larger-than-usual end-of-sentence period.
2. `vim` is smart and suggests you use it, since it is good style to have proper puntuation.
3. See 1.

<sub>The recursive nature of this non-art-like [triptych](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triptych) reminds me of the acronym [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-history.html).</sub>

Comment: Strictly speaking it's not vim but a plugin which invokes a syntax check (lacheck, chktex).