# how to enter a dot with whitespace preceding it?

Tags: punctuation, warnings, vim

I'm getting `Whitespace before punctuation mark in " ."` when I'm trying to enter the word `.Net` with whitespace before it.

How can I fix that? What's the proper way of entering a `.` with whitespace preceding it?

Comment: `.` is a normal character so `this is .NET` would have a word-space before `.NET` what problem did you get?

Comment: Oh is that a warning from an editor? The warning is wrong, but you should say which editor that is (as such it is not really a TeX question).

Comment: Are you trying to enter white space in math mode?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes it's a warning in VIM, not sure how to get it out, I'll learn to live with it.

Comment: @chico just use emacs, you know it makes sense:-)

Comment: @MaxGraves no, I'm not. It's normal text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well... I see a fight, it's not gonna be productive, I'm out... ;-)

Comment: You could probably silence the warning with something like `this is\space.Net`

Comment: `\newcommand{\dotnet}{.Net}` would solve. As well as avoiding `vim`. `;-)`

Comment: @david, egreg: oh you don't want to go there. Vanilla vi(m) doesn't do such nonsense, so it must be something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing it right... as opposed to [You're doing it wrong](http://www.doingitwrong.com/)...

Depending on your workflow, it seems you're including [`lacheck`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lacheck). From the [`lacheck` documentatation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/lacheck/lacheck.pdf):

> "...Sequences of whitespace followed by punctuation marks are also caught."

The output (warnings) from `lacheck` is filled with suggestions or guidelines to help improve typesetting and doesn't matter in this particular case. It's just a warning here and should not deter you from your typesetting adventures. In fact, the following is taken from the BUGS section of the documentation:

> `lacheck` gets confused by advanced  macros,  is  fooled  by
>      simple  macros, can't figure out if you use a non-standard
>      way to switch italic on or off, does not like TeX at  all,
>      does  not  provide  any options to turn off specific warnings, 
>      and is at best a crude approximation.

So I'll stress again, you're doing it right when you consider dropping it from your regular workflow.

Comment: so, I think it's probably some extra useless editor check running on my editor.

Comment: @chico: You have [a VIM plugin installed that runs in the background](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38842/what-does-missing-before-error-mean-in-vim#comment99453_38844) as part of the compilation process, I presume.