# Vim complains of Whitespace error with \hspace

Tags: errors, vim

When I type the following line in Vim:

```
\hrule height .1mm
```

Why do I get the following error in the Vim Location List:

```
foo.tex|258 error| Whitespace before punctation mark in " ."
```

NOTE: It actually says *punctation* for some reason, and not *punctuation*

Comment: As an emacs user I'm inclined to give any number of flippant answers, but, while you wait for a real answer, why not use `0.1mm`..?  (If you aren't already.)

Comment: @jon Worked like a charm. I thought i had to put curly brackets somewhere.

Comment: Without knowing something about your vim configuration it is difficult to say. I assume you are using a plugin of some sort to handle `.tex` files but there are several possibilities plus your own customisation. Certainly I can copy and past that line into a `.tex` document using vim without error.

Comment: @cfr I see. I thought this was one of those *add a comment at end of line issues which is inherent to the tex compiler* problems

Comment: Sorry? I have no idea what you are talking about. But likely somebody else will.

Comment: This is very similar in nature to [What does 'missing `\@` before…' error mean in vim?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38842/5764) You probably have a plug-in installed that checks for this kind of thing (like [`lacheck`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lacheck)), and mistakenly interpreted the `.1mm` as being a sentence-ending period that was preceded by a space.

Comment: Does `\hrule height 0.1mm` help?