# I have a word "Prof" repeating in my Latex document. Can I make a string variable which can be used for later references?

Tags: macros

I am writing a long document which references various Profs (and their names ) in my document. I wanted to make some variable so that I can just use that whenever I wanted to write "***Prof***.".  Is there a way to do this ?

Don't misunderstand for the "Reference", for I just wanted to write the word "***Prof***." using that command.

Comment: `\def\Prof{Prof.}` or `\newcommand{\prof}{Prof.}`, assuming there is no such command already and if it should be bold, use `\newcommand{\Prof}{\textbf{Prof.}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend going for

```
\newcommand*{\prof}[1]{Prof.~#1}
```

And using it like:

```
I'd like to thank \prof{Johnson}.
```

I think adding spaces at the end of commands because they get "gobbled up" is bad practice.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your last statement. But please note that `Prof. #1` could leave a slightly too large space between "Prof." and the name in languages with `\nonfrenchspacing`. Christian's answer shows how to avoid that with `Prof.\@` (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2229/35864 for much more detail and the alternative `Prof.\ #1`). Though I would be tempted to go for `Prof.~#1` here to avoid ('Prof.//Smith') where '//' is a line break.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\newcommand{\Prof}{Prof.\@}` as a possible macro for replacing the text easily with a single change.

Be careful about using `\Prof` in conjunction with text later on (which is very likely), since whitespace is gobbled and the text is glued to the expansion of `\Prof.`

If you don't mind be struck down by the thunderbolts by egreg use `xspace` ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Prof}{Prof.\@}

\begin{document}
Correct: Dear \Prof\ Arthur Gumby from the Ministry of Silly Walks. 

Correct: Dear \Prof{} Arthur Gumby from the Ministry of Silly Walks. 

Wrong: Dear \Prof Arthur Gumby from the Ministry of Silly Walks. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe even `\newcommand{\Prof}{Prof.\@}` (assuming it is never used at the end of a sentence)

Comment: @clemens unlikely, but can this prevent the wrapping of the name Prof. Arthur Gumby, such that Arthur Gumby goes to the next line?

Comment: `\@` affects the spacing after a dot (when `\nonfrenchspacing` is active). In your MWE you have the default `\nonfrenchspacing` which means the space after a dot (except if it follows an uppercase letter) is a little bit longer than between words. An `\@` after the dot prevents this.

Comment: @clemens: Too much typographical detail for me ;-) (Thanks)

Comment: In German documents this usually isn't relevant: `babel` and `ngerman` sets `\frenchspacing`. [Is a period after an abbreviation the same as an end of sentence period?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/question/2229/)

Comment: @clemens: I would suggest to use `\newcommand{\Pf}[1]{Foo}` to let it expand to `Prof. Foo`