# Too much space after an abbreviation period in tt mode

Tags: spacing, punctuation, typography, typewriter

Is there any way to reduce the space between "CTRL." and "OUT", in the following text?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Press the button \texttt{CTRL. OUT} in the controller.\\
Press the button \texttt{CTRL.\ OUT} in the controller.\\
Press the button \texttt{CTRL.\@ OUT} in the controller.\\
Press the button \texttt{CTRL\@. OUT} in the controller.\\
Press the button \texttt{CTRL\@.\@ OUT} in the controller.\\
Press the button \texttt{CTRL.~OUT} in the controller.
\end{document}
```

Nothing seems to work as stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/is-a-period-after-an-abbreviation-the-same-as-an-end-of-sentence-period).

Comment: In my opinion, the spacing is correct (except in the fourth case). You are using a monospaced font, so the space should have the same width as any other glyph... The space is the same with or without abbreviation. It *looks* bigger after an abbreviation because of the white space you see above the period. But if you measure it's actually the same width.

Comment: it seems odd to choose a monospace font and then ask for the space to vary.

Comment: A Unicode monospace font *might* nonetheless have a thin-space character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space and the period have the same width, but the period is almost centered in the allotted width (a bit shifted to the left, see the image below).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\begin{document}
\noindent
1. Press the button \texttt{CTRL. OUT} in the controller.\\
2. Press the button \texttt{CTRLXXOUT} in the controller.\\
3. Press the button \texttt{CTRL.\ OUT} in the controller.\\
4. Press the button \texttt{CTRL.\@ OUT} in the controller.\\
5. Press the button \texttt{CTRL\@. OUT} in the controller.\\
6. Press the button \texttt{CTRL\@.\@ OUT} in the controller.\\
7. Press the button \texttt{CTRL.~OUT} in the controller.

\vrule\texttt{.}\vrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Line 2 shows the widths are the same. After a capital letter, the `\spacefactor` of the period is not relevant. The Computer Modern font however, has a nonzero “extra space” component, which is used when the current space factor is 3000 or more, which is the case of line 5 where `\@.` first sets the space factor to 1000 with `\@` and then the period sets it to 3000. The extra space has a value whose effect is to add a double space. You can realize this with

```
\texttt{ctrl. out}
```

as well.

If you really want to reduce the space after the period, you have to do it manually, say with

```
\texttt{CTRL.\hspace{0.3em}OUT}
```

Example:

```
\bigskip
\noindent
\texttt{CTRL. OUT}\\
\texttt{CTRL.\hspace{0.3em}OUT}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Phelype that there's not an error here, but if you'd like to directly manipulate the spacing you can do something like this:

```
   Press the button \texttt{CTRL.\kern0.1emOUT} in the controller.\\
```

The result of the above is the last line in the image below; the lines above are from your MWE.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My shortest answer in this site: `\,`