# Variation of spacing in between words

Tags: spacing

I'd like to ask if some variation of spacing in between words is normal? In some cases it seems to me that after a full stop and the next words there is a larger space than usual.

The pictures hopefully shows what I mean. The space is before "Another finding..."

I'm seeing this in various locations throughout the document. Is there an explanation for this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: It looks a bit odd, but without the code it is difficult to debug.  Your quote symbols are wrong.

Comment: Add `\frenchspacing` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is a period after an abbreviation the same as an end of sentence period?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2229/5764)

Answer (score 5):

tex follows the u.s. (typewriting) tradition of having a wider space to indicate the end of a sentence.  this will be applied after any punctuation mark that ordinarily occurs at the end of a sentence -- period (full stop), question mark, or exclamation point.  a space slightly wider than an ordinary interword space but not as wide as an end-of-sentence space is applied after colons, semicolons or commas.  to have spaces that are entirely uniform in width, use `\frenchspacing` (as noted in a comment by @egreg).

this tradition is culturally conditioned.  in a context where abbreviations are rampant (e.g., in a physician's directions as to how a prescription is to be taken, or in some legal documents), it does make it easier to determine where sentences end, provided care is taken to distinguish in the input.

unless `\frenchspacing` is used, it is recommended to insert a "`\`" (slash space) after abbreviations that end with a lowercase letter before the period, so that they will not be mistaken for the end of a sentence, or leave unsightly gaps in the middle of text.