# Capital first letter after a period

Tags: capitalization

I expected latex to automatically display the first letter after a period in uppercase, as I'm used to in MS Word, but turns out it doesn't, and I can't find anyone mentioning this on the internet nor all the latex documentations I checked. I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hmmm... lazy much? Why don't you hold down the Shift key for that next character?

Comment: This is no feature of LaTeX (and it should be none, because I find this automatic uppercasing after periods extremely annoying -- in the rare cases I am forced to use the software that must not be named here ;-))

Comment: The auto-correct/complete "feature" of Word is one of the reasons I use LaTeX.  Having software try to outsmart you can lead to typesetting disaster, for example math variables made uppercase, when you are not expecting or wanting it.

Comment: Actually I do it myself but this is a group project and not all members care to do it, and it gives me a headache checking everything afterwards. Also, I wouldn't mind pointing me to the package that helps or the possible methods and I would do the search.

Comment: What is the  full stop actually belongs to an acronym? Should the first letter after `i.e.` or `e.g.`  be capitalised?

Comment: Oh it makes sense to keep it that way. Guess it's gonna stay a manual thing. Thank you.

Comment: There is one such automatic bit of reformatting: LaTeX does [format spaces after periods differently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/is-a-period-after-an-abbreviation-the-same-as-an-end-of-sentence-period), which is why you’re supposed to write `Mr.\ McGoo.` Your editor might or might not auto-capitalize.

Answer (score 7):

In opposite to Word, LibreOffice and the like, you have to distinguish cleary the editor from the »LaTeX« machinery. The editor is used to type the text. So if you'd like to have a kind of autocorrection, find an editor who does this job for you. There is a real long list here: [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/4736)

After saving the file your texlive / miktex / whatever installation produces a PDF from your file, but it does not change the *.tex file. You just get a PDF and some auxiliary files.

By the way, you could even use the word window as editor. If I'm to lazy for proof reading, I sometimes copy my text into a word window and wait, what Word marks up as error.

Comment: "use the word window as editor", it's a potentially good idea, but beware of getting back characters like `–`. Out of the box, non-unicode, default encoding LaTeX will not print this

Comment: @Au101 Yes, you are right. I don't change the text in the word window. I just use the markup to check for typos.